# Open .nml (fortran namelist file) in python (ValueError)

Tags: python, xml, pandas, parsing, fortran

I use `f90nml` to open a `.nml` file (Fortran namelist file) in python using this code:

```
import f90nml
nml = f90nml.read('D:\data.nml')
```

But it returns this error:

```
  File "D:\...\tokenizer.py", line 101, in parse
    raise ValueError
```

My folder also contains a `.dtd` file. The below image is a part of `.nml` file (closed form):

[image]

How can I import this type of file to python and convert it to data-frame?

Comment: If the image is of D:\data.nml, then that file does not contain a `NAMELIST`.

Comment: @Steve Yes. It's the first block of this file.

Comment: It's not platform independent, but I've had good luck using numpy's tofile and fromfile to exchange binary files with fortran

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "Yes.".  "Yes, it is not a namelist"  or "Yes, it is a namelist, but written in XML".  Fortran namelist format predates XML by a few decades.

Comment: The snapshot is clearly not a Fortran namelist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like maybe that file is using `XML` and not actually a `Namelist` file. Fortran Namelist files tend to follow the structure below

```
&Title
key1 = value1,
key2 = value2, 
/
```

`f90nml` assumes the file contains one or more of the namelist entries in the form above. 
You can parse the XML file using python's built in [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) object. Then do whatever you need to do to get it into the database format.

Answer (score -2):

Difficult to figure out without a full set of data but I would suggest looking at pynml since it seems to have a lot more functionality than f90nml.
https://pynml.readthedocs.io/pynml/pynml.manager.html

Comment: That module is for a "Network Markup Language (NML)" file, not a Fortran namelist.